# In Eclipse, is it possible to find, where, a certain function, class or variable is called?

Tags: java, eclipse

When you want to open the declaration of a class/function/variable in java you can press Ctrl and click on it, but is there are way to go the other way round? If you had to find all instances where a function or variable is called how would you quickly get that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> shows you all the places where a variable or method is used or called.

Comment: And for Mac? Most likely, just turn Ctrl into Cmd. Might be worth checking though.

Comment: Got the question the other way around.

Comment: As far as I can tell, on a Mac you have to point at a symbol while pressing Cmd. A tiny context menu opens up containing two items: `Open Declaration` and `Open Implementation`.

Answer (score 5):

On both Windows and Mac, right-click the method, and choose "Open Call Hierarchy."

You can use this for identifiers other than methods. For example, if a class does not have an explicit constructor, you can use this to find all the callers of its default constructor.